# How to create a single line/edge from a set of superimposing lines/edges in MATLAB?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, matlab

I have a set of edges detected from an image using edge detector of MATLAB's computer vision toolbox. All these edges (18 of them) just form two lines. How do I get the lines from these edges? All that I am interested is to find the intersection point of these two lines.

edges looklike [image]

and the hough lines look like [image]

Comment: Can you show what the image look like?

Comment: Try asking at http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Peter Kovesi's [CV website](http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/~pk/research/matlabfns/) contains a great set of functions for line detection. Look at [this](http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/~pk/research/matlabfns/LineSegments/example/index.html) example of using them.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that the intention is to find the "center point" here goes a possible way (not MATLAB specific though):

Clarifications: when you mention

> All these edges (18 of them) just form two lines

It's actually two *components* or *contours* that are formed. The Hough line transform will give you straight lines: not exactly what you wanted it seems.

Also, the two "lines" or "contours" do not intersect at least from what's seen in the picture. If you want to find the point of closest approach traverse each point on one contour and check the distance between that point and the points on the second contour. Find the minimum distance for each point on the contour. Then select the minimum from that.

If you meant intersection of two straight lines, simply solve the two equations (you can get them from knowing the end-points of the lines).